# Persistent pointer to parent

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, model

How can I use `this` as a persistent pointer, so it would work outside of the current scope?

As for this example, I don't know how should I set the `fx.parent`:

```
class Effect
{
    Card* parent;
};

class Card
{
    vector<Effect> effects;
    void addEffect(Effect);
};

Card::addEffect(Effect fx)
{
    /*
     * the `this` pointer is not persistent and
     * will not work outside of this scope
     */
    fx.parent = this; 
    this->effects.push_back(fx);
}
```

PS: I'd be grateful for any literature about when pointers get destroyed, invalidated, etc. I could not really find anything readable. Nothing at all, actually.

Comment: You should probably [read a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) about C++.

Comment: @FredOverflow Indeed I should, but also I need to get this fixed now.

Comment: @Mikulas: what makes you think that code is wrong?

Comment: Is `Effect` a polymorphic base class or not?

Comment: @FredOverflow Nope, it is not. @Mat I might have made the example too plain. I have some containers etc. above these classes. I set the parent, breakpoint somewhere a bit later, and the very same object does not have a valid pointer then.

Comment: @Mat: It is because he links to a local variable that goes out of scope, see my answer.

Comment: I was kind of assuming that we had only a partial view of the code and that Effect has proper copy/assignment operators/constructors.

Comment: Are the Cards also in a vector or something? That's probably the cause of the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing elements into containers copies them. So you should link the copy, not the original:

```
Card::addEffect(Effect fx)
{
    effects.push_back(fx);
    effects.back().parent = this;
}
```

Otherwise, you will link to a local variable that goes out of scope when `addEffect` returns.

Note that this code generates another copy because of pass-by-value. Let's get rid of that:

```
Card::addEffect(Effect const& fx)
{
    effects.push_back(fx);
    effects.back().parent = this;
}
```

Also note that as soon as the capacity is exhausted, the vector will do an internal reallocation, and all pointers will become invalid. The easiest workaround is to reserve enough space from the beginning:

```
Card::Card()
{
    effects.reserve(1000);   // never more than 1000 effects at once
}
```

If that is unacceptable to you, you must either use a different container (`std::list<Effect>`) or put your effects on the heap and manage them manually (`std::vector<Effect*>`) or with a smart pointer (`std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Effect> >`).

Comment: Why is that? I mean, of course that `push_back` copies, but why does not the copied object have the very same pointer set? Shouldn't the copy contain everything the original object does? (in the first level at least for a shallow copy)

Comment: @Mik: It's not the contents that matter, but the identity.

Comment: Thanks, this exhaustive answer is extraordinary valuable to me.

Comment: Shouldn't every copy of an `Effect` make a shallow copy of `Card* parent` and therefore shouldn't the copies not matter?

Comment: @Xeo: You are right, of course. I somehow assumed that the problem had to do with pointers to effects :(

Comment: @FredOverflow Now that I am reading this again, I have an urgent temptation to point out that I was not being sarcastic. I meant that I am actually thankful for the whole answer above. Hope I made it clear now : )

Answer (score 2):

The `this` pointer of an object is the same as taking the address:

```
#inclide <iostream>

class X{
public:
    X* GetThis(){
        return this;
    }
};

int main(){
    X x;
    X* addr_x = &x;
    X* this_x = x.GetThis();
    if(addr_x == this_x)
        std::cout << "Both are the same" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Shouldn't happen" << std::endl;
}
```

[See at Ideone.](http://ideone.com/EHtsb)
As such, `this` is just a normal pointer to your class with a special name, so there's no problem with your code regarding the use of `this`. Aside from that, there are some errors though, like the missing return type in the definition of `Card::addEffect` and `Card* parent` in `class Effect` being private and as such it cannot be accessed by `Card`.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Also, I made the example way too simple, I am aware that it would not compile like this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it goes like this:

First of all the keyword "**this**" means the current object.
So in this context:

```
Card::addEffect(Effect fx)
{
    fx.parent = this; 
    this->effects.push_back(fx);
}
```

**this** is the **Card** object in which the **addEffect()** function was called..

Second, pointers don't get invalidated or destroyed. You can destroy the object they are pointing at by using the **delete** operator:

```
Blah* pointer = new Blah();
delete pointer;
```

Comment: I know that `this` is a pointer to the `Card` object. That is why I used it as a parent in the first place. Thanks for pointing out that the pointer is never invalidated, I suppose I must have made an error somewhere else.

Comment: `delete` doesn't "destroy a pointer". It destroys *what the pointer points to*. The pointer itself is "destroyed" (a no-op) when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

The way you keep track of your card object can also cause problems. When a copy is made of your card object the parent pointers will keep pointing to the original Card object. You will need to write a copy constructor to solve this issue or prevent copying from happening.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, luckily I never copy a card so this is slightly easier.